# How to optimize a very slow query?

Tags: mysql

I have this table structure. id is primary key:

```
 id  post_id  email  telegram twitter  address  refer_link  referrer
```

Here is `show create table`:

```
CREATE TABLE `wpkx_airdrop_claim` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `post_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `telegram` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
 `twitter` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
 `facebook` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 `discord` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
 `address` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
 `refer_link` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
 `referrer` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
 `ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
 KEY `post_id_index` (`post_id`)
)
```

Table is now relatively big. When I run this query (it has around 9k rows) it takes more than 30 seconds to execute:

```
SELECT o.email
    ,telegram
    ,twitter
    ,address
    ,IFNULL((
            SELECT email
            FROM wpkx_airdrop_claim
            WHERE o.referrer = refer_link
            ), '') AS refer_email
    ,(
        SELECT count(referrer)
        FROM wpkx_airdrop_claim
        WHERE referrer = o.refer_link
        ) AS refer_count
FROM wpkx_airdrop_claim AS o
WHERE post_id = 8037
ORDER BY refer_count DESC
```

This query counts number of same values in `referrer` column, and group it with the value of `refer_link` column. It gets how many referrals user have.
It is explained in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52538612/mysql-create-view-from-columns-from-same-table

Any idea how to optimize this query to execute it faster?

Thank you.

Comment: `explain <your query>`  is something to be run and the output copied to the question. It should be done for every query performance problem. It isn't a conceptual request for a better explanation (though that often helps).

Comment: I hope it is still InnoDB?

Answer (score 1):

> give me an example how to do it

Get something like

```
SELECT t1.email
     , t1.telegram
     , t1.twitter
     , t1.address
     , COALESCE(t2.email, '') AS refer_email
     , count(t3.referrer) AS refer_count
FROM wpkx_airdrop_claim AS t1
LEFT JOIN wpkx_airdrop_claim AS t2 ON t1.referrer = t2.refer_link
LEFT JOIN wpkx_airdrop_claim AS t3 ON t3.referrer = t1.refer_link
WHERE t1.post_id = 8037
GROUP BY t1.id
/* If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, replace with
GROUP BY t1.email
       , t1.telegram
       , t1.twitter
       , t1.address
       , COALESCE(t2.email, '') AS refer_email
*/
ORDER BY refer_count DESC
```

And create indices by: `(post_id, referrer, refer_link)`, `(referrer)` and `(refer_link)`. Then test does they are used.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have tried this query. It actually runs slower. It takes 42 sec to execute, against 31 sec previously.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE post_id = 8037
```

begs for `INDEX(post_id)` !  That will speed it up by a few orders of magnitude.

And `INDEX(referrer)`

And `INDEX(refer_link, email)`

9K rows is "small".

Indexes are often the solution to performance of queries.  More: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Index summary:

Currently:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
KEY `post_id_index` (`post_id`)
```

Recommended

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `post_id_index` (`post_id`),
INDEX(referrer),
INDEX(refer_link, email)
```

Note that the PK is a UNIQUE KEY, so your second index on `id` is redundant.

Comment: Hello. I have created an index for post_id. There is no performance improvement.
Should I also try adding other indexes you have suggested? Only referal_link column is unique. Thanks.

Comment: @AnteMedic - The `CREATE TABLE` you provided does not show that index??  More than that, there is no `referal_link`????  A `UNIQUE` is already an `INDEX`, so no need for that one.  Yes to the other one.  If there are still issues, pleas add an updated `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to your Question so we can look for other issues.

Comment: Sorry, column is is `refer_link`. I have updated the `show create table`. Should I also ad your suggested indexes? Thanks.

Comment: @AnteMedic - Yes, see my update.